# There is any IRC command to ignore a person?

Tags: irc

I want to clear my IRC channel view from a certain bot messages. It is possible?

In http://webchat.freenode.net/ i can't ignore a bot with /ignore. How can I do it?

Comment: let me guess... sobot?

Comment: @Martinho exactly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IRC protocol doesn't provide any commands for this. Certain programs that use the protocol have ignore features while others don't.

Comment: This is orthogonal. 'ignore' may or may not be part of the protocol.

Answer (score 27):

Yes, just use the [`/ignore [user]`](http://www.livinginternet.com/r/ra_ignore.htm) command.

Answer (score 11):

A bit of extra info, you can also do /ignore user@host or /ignore *@host which is useful if people change nicks

Answer (score 3):

Try

/ignore (botname) chan

or

/ignore (botname) all

The first ignores in channel, the second says in all situations.

Answer (score 2):

```
/ignore -c user*!@*
```

For Example:

`/ignore -c XDCCBOT*!@*` will ignore all users with XDCCBOT prefix. I.e. XDCCBOT1234@anyhost.com

The `-c` flag is to ignore messages from user sent to the Channel only, and you will still be able to recieve CTCP/DCC replies etc.

Answer (score 1):

[/ignore](http://www.ircbeginner.com/ircinfo/m-commands.html) usually works

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can do:

> /ignore user